# What is it when sharing import modules between python processes

Tags: python

I thought when i fork a process then it shares the imported module as it's parent, so I tested as below:

lock2.py:

```
import multiprocessing

lock=multiprocessing.Semaphore()
a=[]
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import lock2
import time

def func():
    with lock2.lock:
        print "start------"
        time.sleep(5)
        lock2.a.append(1)
        print lock2.a
        print "end--------"

for i in range(5):
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
    p.start()
```

when test.py is called, the output is:

```
start------
[1]
end--------
start------
[1]
end--------
start------
[1]
end--------
start------
[1]
end--------
start------
[1]
end--------
```

It's so weird, the object `lock` is shared(because it works) between processes except object `a` (becase it should be `[1,1,1,1,1]` as shared).

Somebody can explain to me how python shares the imported modules between processes.

Comment: What OS and Python version are you using? The default for Windows is `spawn` which creates a new python interpreter for each thread. `fork` is only on Unixes. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods for the Python 3 docs. The Python 2 docs don't mention this, but I expect it would be the same.

Comment: i use python2.7 on mac os